# Compress a series of 1s and 0s into the shortest possible ascii string

Tags: python, compression, base64, coffeescript

How could you convert a series of `1`s and `0`s into the shortest possible form consisting of URL safe ascii characters?

eg.

```
s = '00100101000101111010101'
compress(s)
```

**Resulting in something like:**

`Ysi8aaU`

**And obviously:**

`decompress(compress(s)) == s`

(I ask this question purely out of curiousity)

Comment: base64 is a fairly standard encoding for this kind of problem. if i could afford more time, i would write up a proper answer. give it a look though

Comment: If I convert the string directly using base64 I actually end up with a longer string, even though each character now has about 100 times as many possibilities.

Comment: I think there was an implicit "convert the string of 1s and 0s into bytes first" there...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the solution I came up with (+ far too many comments):

```
# A set of 64 characters, which allows a maximum chunk length of 6 .. because
# int('111111', 2) == 63 (plus zero)
charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_'

def encode(bin_string):
    # Split the string of 1s and 0s into lengths of 6.
    chunks = [bin_string[i:i+6] for i in range(0, len(bin_string), 6)]
    # Store the length of the last chunk so that we can add that as the last bit
    # of data so that we know how much to pad the last chunk when decoding.
    last_chunk_length = len(chunks[-1])
    # Convert each chunk from binary into a decimal
    decimals = [int(chunk, 2) for chunk in chunks]
    # Add the length of our last chunk to our list of decimals.
    decimals.append(last_chunk_length)
    # Produce an ascii string by using each decimal as an index of our charset.
    ascii_string = ''.join([charset[i] for i in decimals])

    return ascii_string

def decode(ascii_string):
    # Convert each character to a decimal using its index in the charset.
    decimals = [charset.index(char) for char in ascii_string]
    # Take last decimal which is the final chunk length, and the second to last
    # decimal which is the final chunk, and keep them for later to be padded
    # appropriately and appended.
    last_chunk_length, last_decimal = decimals.pop(-1), decimals.pop(-1)
    # Take each decimal, convert it to a binary string (removing the 0b from the
    # beginning, and pad it to 6 digits long.
    bin_string = ''.join([bin(decimal)[2:].zfill(6) for decimal in decimals])
    # Add the last decimal converted to binary padded to the appropriate length
    bin_string += bin(last_decimal)[2:].zfill(last_chunk_length)

    return bin_string
```

**So:**

```
>>> bin_string = '000111000010101010101000101001110'
>>> encode(bin_string)
'hcQOPgd'
>>> decode(encode(bin_string))
'000111000010101010101000101001110'
```

**And here it is in CoffeeScript:**

```
class Urlify
    constructor: ->
        @charset = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-_'

    encode: (bits) ->
        chunks = (bits[i...i+6] for i in [0...bits.length] by 6)
        last_chunk_length = chunks[chunks.length-1].length
        decimals = (parseInt(chunk, 2) for chunk in chunks)
        decimals.push(last_chunk_length)
        encoded = (@charset[i] for i in decimals).join('')

        return encoded

    decode: (encoded) ->
        decimals = (@charset.indexOf(char) for char in encoded)
        [last_chunk_length, last_decimal] = [decimals.pop(), decimals.pop()]
        decoded = (('00000'+d.toString(2)).slice(-6) for d in decimals).join('')
        last_chunk = ('00000'+last_decimal.toString(2)).slice(-last_chunk_length)
        decoded += last_chunk

        return decoded
```

Comment: Typo in your CoffeeScript code: In `encode`, you name the argument `raw` but then refer to it as `bits`. Once those are made consistent, it works great. :)

Answer (score 6):

As one of the comments mentioned, using base64 would probably be the way to go. However, you don't want to stick the binary in without some converting.

Two options are converting to int first then packing:

```
import base64

s = '0110110'
n = int(s, 2)

result = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(n)).rstrip('=')
```

The other option would be to use the struct module to pack the value into a binary format and use this. (The code below is from http://www.fuyun.org/2009/10/how-to-convert-an-integer-to-base64-in-python/)

```
import base64
import struct

def encode(n):
  data = struct.pack('<Q', n).rstrip('\x00')
  if len(data)==0:
    data = '\x00'
  s = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(data).rstrip('=')
  return s

def decode(s):
  data = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(s + '==')
  n = struct.unpack('<Q', data + '\x00'* (8-len(data)) )
  return n[0]
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! With the first solution, the leading 0 is lost in the conversion using `int()`. When I tried the second solution: `>>> encode('001010101')` -> `struct.error: cannot convert argument to long`

Comment: Oops, The argument '<Q' is used to specify the formatting. Check out http://docs.python.org/library/struct.html for something that might help you get it in there properly since you'll want to use a string and not a numeric value to make sure you preserve the 0's.

Comment: What about the answer I just posted? Would that result in the shortest possible string? Is there anything I'm doing that isn't necessary?

Answer (score 1):

I would convert 8 of those 0's and 1's to bytes using a lookup table and then encode those bytes with base64.

Comment: How would I go about doing this? Would it not cause me to loose the leading 00 at the beginning of the string when converting it into a byte?

Comment: No, you'd just need to add some padding to get a multiple of 8.

Comment: The python code that would actually make this happen would be really interesting to see if anyone has the time.